# design - state of object handled externally

Tags: java, oop

got a design related question:

I've got an abstract class player with subclasses AIPlayer, HumanPlayer, NetworkPlayer, etc as well as class GameManager.

When player makes moves, different types of cards are given to the player which can be used in later moves.

Where should I store cards available to player?

Solution 1:
Store in abstract class Player with getter and setter methods.

Problem,, subclass could, through bad coding accidentally change what cards the player has.  i.e. problem is that the setter method is available to the subclasses of Player when it should really only be available to the GameManager - as the GameManager is the only class that should be allowed to award cards.

Solution 2:
Create unmodifiable class PlayerState and store a private map in GameManager from Player to PlayerState.  Now GameManager can manage state of Player as in what cards they own  but subclasses of Player can only retrieve the PlayerState objects from the GameManager, they cannot change it.

Problem, over kill?  I mean the players are objects themselves yet they use another object to get their state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it depends on where you put your game logic:

- **If most of the logic is very general** and thus in the GameManager, it would be easier to manage the cards for each player in the GameManager as well. You could actually maintain a private `Map` storing the cards for each player in GameManager, and make the cards visible to Player and its implementations by wrapping those maps inside an unmodifiable map, created like `Collections.unmodifiableMap()`.
- **If most of the logic is highly player specific** and there is not much interaction with other players, the logic would be best placed in the Player or Player implementations. In this case you could directly maintain a modifiable `Set` of cards within the abstract Player.

But always keep in mind that you will always be able to screw things up by making coding mistakes, if not in Player then in GameManager. So the difference should be quite small.